# WCF Trailing Slashes

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-6

My situation is I have a WCF service and a generic contract that works for all collections:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "GetAllService", ConfigurationName = "GetAllContract")]
public interface IGetAllCollectionServiceContract<T> where T : IEnumerable
{
    [Audit]
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
    T GetAll();
}
```

This works nicely when you use a trailing / on the end but if you don't you get "No data received" message. I have tried removing the "/" from the UriTemplate but this gives the exact same result. What is strange about this is that I deployed this code to our live servers months ago and on the live server it seems to add a forward slash on the end of the url when you navigate to it. On the staging server it doesn't do this but there is no difference in the code, the basic IIS settings or the web config that I can see that would effect this. I am using IIS 6 and visual studio 2012 can you guys think of anything that would cause this issue? I have read the other posts about this and they have not helped.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wierd as it may seem the problem was in the web config in some diagnostic code once the below was removed this worked... very strange

```
<system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
```